# IIS Express doesn't start on first try, but starts fine after that. How do I troubleshoot?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-express

I'm running Visual Studio Professional 2012, and recently IIS Express tries to spin up on the first attempt when I'm debugging an asp.net mvc app. It eventually times out and I get an error dialog that Visual Studio was unable to start IIS Express. If I press run/debug again, it starts the browser as expected and navigates to the site. It's basically just annoying as this happens several times a day. I've looked in the windows event logs and I cant seem to find anything related to IIS Express or Visual Studio errors.  I would really like to resolve this problem as it used to start normally all the time. It must be some extension or something I may have added to Visual Studio. I'm pretty stuck at this point. Does anyone have any suggestions of how I can troubleshoot this most annoying problem? Thanks for any tips or tricks that lead to a solution.

Comment: Anything logged in Event Viewer?

Comment: as my post says no. I dont see anything in the event viewer

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. It's probably not what you think.

Visual Studio, for ASP.NET (+MVC) projects, tries to start launching a URL. This URL may not match what you have deployed your IIS Express site to.

Right click on your web project and pick `Properties`. Select `Web`, and under `Use Local IIS Web Server` make sure it has the right URL.

You may still have problems debugging; you can use `Attach to Process` to connect to `iisexpress.exe`.